# While setting the text box value to a XML Element Value throws a null reference exception

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a an XML as follows:

```
<E:Events xmlns:E="Event-Details">
 <Date>12/27/2012</Date>
  <Time>‎11:12 PM</Time>
<Message>Happy Anniversary guyss!!!..</Message>
</E:Events>
```

After I have retrieved the element values i.e. `12/27/2012`, `11:12 PM`,`Happy Anniversary guyss!!!..`, by following code:

```
XElement read = new XElement.Parse(a.ReadToEnd()); 
read.Element("Date").Value;  //retrieves the Date value and 
read.Element("Message").Value; //retrieves the Time Value.
```

i try to assign these values to my xaml UI elements.

e.g.

```
DateTime dt;
dt = DateTime.Parse(read.Element("Date").Value)    
datepicker.Value = dt

 OR

txtMessage.Text = (read.Element("Message").Value)
```

Both give NullReferenceException. So I can't assign my UI elements the XML values retrieved.

Any Help on this is Appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code of how you storing these values? As in examples of the date value retrieved and text message retrieved. Also, when you get an exception the details should tell you which object has the problem. Check it .

Comment: Add tags if it is winforms, wpf, silverlight, asp.net

Comment: string a = "xyz.xml" (my above XML file)
After I load the XML i.e. XElement read = new XElement.Parse(a.ReadToEnd());
read.Element("Date").Value - retrieves the Date value and
read.Element("Message").Value - retrieves the Time Value.
I have a datepicker and textbox in my MainPage.xaml,
I try to assign the datepicker value and textbox.Text value to this retrieved values.

Comment: Can you update your question and post your whole flow as is? A null reference exception could be because you are making these calls at a wrong place or disposing off your XElement or the values obtained form it.

Comment: Is it fine now??..
After I have retrieved values from the XML, I directly assign the values to the UI text box.
I also tried to re-load my MainPage.xaml page but that too didnt help.
I hope I am clear now??..

Comment: Please post the full section of code where you are actually parsing the string values out of the XML. There is an XML namespace in play here which could be causing you to return an empty string when you are trying to parse values from the XML which would result in a null reference

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check if `datepicker` and `txtMessage` controls are initialized (eg not `null`) at the moment your snippet is running.

`NullReferenceException` is very specific and easy-to-locate error if you see whole code. To help we must see completely same code that fires exception.

Comment: I tried to Initialize my MainPage again, and then the textbox.Text took the xml assigned value.

Comment: please be more precise - your snippet doesn't contain `textbox.Text`. Also, when exception is thrown are controls initialized (when hover they should be non-null)? If yes, you should post your current sample for us to help

Answer (score 0):

I tried to Initialize my MainPage again, by calling InitializeComponent() method again, and it took my values.

Thank you guys for all the help.